# Traveling from Tbilisi to Kazbegi?

Tags: transportation, tips-and-tricks, georgia-country

I would like to take a minibus from Tbilisi to Kazbegi, but I do not speak Georgian and not sure where is the furtherest point that the minibus will take me.. I imagine I will need a taxi to get to my hotel in Kazbegi from the minibus stop.

Will it be easy to get a taxi ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The minibuses leaving from Didube station in Tbilisi cost about GEL10 and take around three hours; they'll take you into Kazbegi (Stepantsminda) town. You don't need to speak Georgian. The signs for the Kazbegi minibuses are (at least often) in the Latin alphabet in addition to Georgian--although Kazbegi is often transliterated as Qazbegi--and the drivers will speak enough English to work out the essentials with tourists.

Kazbegi (Stepantsminda) town is a small place, and there are always people willing to drive you from the minibus station to anywhere in the surrounds (including your hotel) for the right price.